# How to generate unique code from occurrence in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my pandas dataframe

```
Id Code
1  A_01
2  C_03
3  A_01
4  C_02
5  C_03
```

My Expected Output

```
Id Code     Unique Code
1  A_01       A_01_0001
2  C_03       C_03_0001
3  A_01       A_01_0002
4  C_02       C_02_0001
5  C_03       C_03_0002
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `cumcount` and `zfill`

```
df['unique_code'] = df['Code'] + '_' + df.groupby('Code').cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(4)
df
Out[386]: 
   Id  Code unique_code
0   1  A_01   A_01_0001
1   2  C_03   C_03_0001
2   3  A_01   A_01_0002
3   4  C_02   C_02_0001
4   5  C_03   C_03_0002
```